# Proving that W-algebra homomorphisms are contractible

Tags: type-theory, higher-category-theory, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

I don't understand the conclusion of the proof of Theorem 5.4.7 of the Homotopy Type Theory text and would like a more detailed explanation of how it works. Here's my attempt at divining an answer.

The theorem states that the type of W-algebra homomorphisms is always contractible (i.e., any two elements of the type are propositionally equal).

A W-algebra homomorphism between types $C$ and $D$ is a (dependent?) pair $(f, s_f)$ such that $f: C \to D$ and $s_f : f \circ s_C = s_D \circ Pf$ where $s_C$ is the successor function of the argument type family $P: A \to \mathcal{U}$ to $C$ and $P$ acts as a functor on $f$ on the RHS.

For any two elements of this type $(f,s_f)$ and $(g,s_g)$, we must show that $(f,s_f) = (g,s_g)$ to prove the theorem. Following the computation rule for equalities on dependent pairs established in an earlier chapter, we start by showing $f = g$. This is immediate given the W-elimination and function extensionality rules, as the proof suggests.

The reason it gives for $s_f = s_g$ is where it becomes inscrutable to me. It gives the two pasting diagrams

[image: pasting diagrams]

and then goes into a bit about algebra 2-cells that has no connection to what came before. (AS AN ASIDE: Does this have something to do with higher category theory? I don't fully understand what an $n$-morphism is. Does it somehow imply that $s_f = s_g$ because types are $(\infty, 1)$-groupoids? It would be great if the book had an appendix about them)

Anyway, returning to the second step of showing equalities between dependent pairs, I would think we would next show $e_*(s_f) = s_g$ where $e : f = g$ was obtained in the previous step and $e_*$ is the transportation function associated to $e$ by the transportation lemma.

The pasting diagram argument seems to suggest that we can infer the equality by substituting appearances of $f$ with $g$ using $e$, and similarly for $Pf$ and $Pg$ using $Pe$ (plus, aren't pasting diagrams meant to be **pasted** together? How on earth do you paste these two?)

But how can that alone suffice to show that $s_f = s_g$? $f$ and $g$ are propositionally equal, not definitionally so. As such, deriving the type of $s_g$ from the value of $s_f$ involves concatenating paths/equalities onto $s_f$, and it's been my understanding so far that this may produce an equality proof distinct from $s_g$ (but sharing its type, of course). Hence, I doubt that $s_f = s_g$ can follow from this observation alone. In other words, I see that I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit point is that $e_*(s_f)=s_g$ is equivalent to the type of equalities from the left-hand pasting diagram to the right-hand pasting diagram.  That is, the two aren't pasted together with each other: the results of the two individual pastings are equated to each other in the type $(s_C \circ Pg) =_{(PW \to C)} (f\circ s_W)$.  Thus, constructing an equality between those two diagrams is equivalent to showing $e_*(s_f)=s_g$, which as you noted is what we obviously need to show $(f,s_f) = (g,s_g)$.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I still don't see why the two proof values coincide. I don't think I understand what you mean by "equated to each other in the type $(s_C \circ Pg) =_{PW \to C} (f \circ s_W)$. How does that induce an equality between the two equalities? The naming of $s_f$ suggests a functional dependency on $f$. Is the type of $s_f$ a mere proposition?

Comment: No, $s_f$ is not a function of $f$; it's just named that way to distinguish it from $s_g$.  And no, its type is not a mere proposition, or we wouldn't have to do any work in the second step.  When I say that "$x$ and $y$ are equated to each other in the type $X$" I mean we have an element of the identity type $x =_X y$.  Does that help?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I don't see where the existence of $s_e$ is shown. I see that $e^*(s_f)$ and $s_g$ occupy the same type but how is the equality proof between them, $s_e$, constructed? To my understanding that step is still missing.

Comment: @Mark $s_e$ is constructed by constructing an element of the type $a = b$, where $a$ and $b$ are the two pastings above which belong to the type $(s_C\circ Pg)=_{(PW\to C)} (f\circ s_W)$, and observing that the type $a=b$ is equivalent to the type $e_*(s_f)=s_g$ to which $s_e$ is intended to belong.

Comment: yes, but where is $s_e$ actually constructed? I don't see where the work is done to show the two diagrams are equal. Its existence is asserted out of thin air AFAICT.

Comment: Well, it is labeled upfront as only a "Sketch of proof"!  The final sentence is intended to indicate how one would construct it: define $e$ by function extensionality and W-elimination, then the resulting computation rule for $e$ allows you to construct $s_e$ also by function extensionality and W-elimination.